# CPU-Z shows all cores stopped

Tags: battery-life, cpu

Is there anybody could help me explain this situation?

By the way, something malicious I don't know (not cpu-z) cause battery drain whereas anti-virus software tells nothing.

[image]

Comment: Well apps are not perfect, so always try another alternative just to be sure. I recommend [OS Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor&hl=en). Go to its Misc tab to see the status of cores. BTW, we prefer to sort different issues through different questions. All of them at the same table makes a mess for us. So, please raise that battery issue in a different question with the research/search you undertook and [edit] out the irrelevant stuff in this question. Thanks

Comment: Since this is custom ROM here it's probably it's fault for this battery drain and showing all cores offline. This is not malware, if it was malware than someone is very bored or something. Ask rom developer and other users are they occurred similar issues. And ffs stop using mobile anti virus software it's pointless and waste of resources.